# Region and Language settings causes text to display incorrectly

Tags: winapi, unicode, vb6

I am having trouble getting Unicode strings to display correctly when the user's "Region and Language" Format settings are set to something other than English.

The code snippet below pulls Unicode strings from a text file (saved as Unicode) and displays them correctly if the Format setting (Region and Language) is set to *English*. If I change it to *Japanese* (the actual language I'm rendering the text in using DrawText) my strings display incorrectly.

Can this setting be overridden? Maybe a better approach exists?

Here is a screenshot of how my strings appear in my application:

[image]

```
Dim lf As LOGFONT
Dim hFont As Long
Dim Result As Long

lf.lfHeight = 13
lf.lfFaceName = "Arial"
lf.lfCharSet = 1

hFont = CreateFontIndirect(lf)

Call SelectObject(lHDC, hFont)
SetTextColor lHDC, RGB(88, 88, 88)
X = StrPtr(StrConv(cap, vbFromUnicode))
DrawText lHDC, X, -1, tR, DT_CENTER
Call DeleteObject(hFont)
```

Comment: It sounds like a codepage issue when converting between Unicode and MBCS. Can you show us the `StrConv()` function body pls?

Comment: If the strings really do start out as Unicode then you shouldn't need to convert them at all, and it is probably this conversion that's causing the problem. If VB6 doesn't support Unicode APIs natively then it's time to move to a more modern language.

Comment: You haven't explained what your code is doing. Your screenshot looks as if you are using a Common Control Tab control. But your code snippet is writing to a device context. Which one? The Common Control? If so, which one? The VB5 version? The VB6 version? The CCRP version? Or is this a custom control you have written yourself? I can guess what the problem is, but speculation based on incorrect facts is pointless.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied! I was able to resolve this by switching from standard file I/O to ADO to read in my strings from a text file saved as UTF-8.